# Getting error while creating library using another library (openssl)

Tags: iphone, ios, openssl, static-libraries

I created a library **using openssl library to generate DiffieHellman key** and to make it simple for the user. I was able create library successfully both for iPhone simulator and device.But while testing my library on device I am getting error for using OpenSSL library function in device.

e.g

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CRYPTO_dbg_malloc", referenced from:
  -[MyLib methodName] in libMyLib.a(MyLib.o)
```

(Note: The library created is for armv7 and armv7s)

If I use the library created for iossimulator it works fine in simulator.

Comment: Please check if _CRYPTO_dbg_malloc is exported in libcrypto.a. If it is not there, you need to recompile.

Comment: @dbasic: It's a third party library dont have source code of it. But yes it does have as it worked fine while using the library for i386.